# Is it halal to use gold phones for men?

Tags: hadith, halal-haram, sunnah, adab, men

There are some electronics like iPhone 5(S), were made of gold.

Is it halal to use them for men?

**My general question is,**

Is it permitted on Islam for men to use gold products(not as a jwell)?

It may be vessels or spoons or shoes or bags or specs or any other products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to the last part...

If they're vessels (like cups and spoons), they're clearly forbidden in the various authentic ahadeeth.

Now to the main part about other than utensils...

Let us first recall the hadeeth from Saheeh al-Bukhaari:

> Al-Halaalu Bayyin, wal-harramu bayyin...
>
> الحلال بيّن والحرام بيّن...

The hadeeth basically explains that the halaal is clear and the haraam is clear. And between that are the things of doubt. So as a general rule, we'd better avoid what is of doubt.

Now, a phone may seem (at first) like a piece of equipment. But then you're going to have to carry it with you. And most people don't just carry a phone. They' (almost) wear it. Either on their necks or on their waste and so on.

So although you're not intentionally wearing it, it's leading to that.

Furthermore, if you take things like spectacles, you're directly wearing it. So this is no different to wearing a necklace.

In conclusion, although there aren't ahadeeth about mobile phones and spectacles in particular, it's best to avoid getting into something that is doubtful.

Wallaahu a'lam.

Comment: most phones, dare I say all phones, have gold present in them(in the form of contacts, wires,  etc...) would you then consider just carrying a phone(in a pocket) to be haraam?  I'm serious in asking and do not want to simply counter your point

Comment: I don't think carrying a phone or for that matter an item of jewellery in the pocket (eg: for delivery to a client) is the same as wearing gold. But my point was that it's best to stay away from matters of doubt.